# Laravel router-link works only the first time

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to fetch results from database in News.vue, and display them in Topnews.vue. I have two links fetched. When I click link1, it shows up the Topnews.vue template with everything working as intended, however, if i click link2, nothing happens, except for that the URL changes, but the template does not show up the result. If i refresh the page and click link2 or click on the navbar, then link2, it shows up, and same, clicking then link1, changes the URL, but doesnt show up. I'm really stuck on that and I'd be really glad if you help me out on that issue. Hope you understand.

News.vue

```
<template id="news">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="cars" v-for="row in filteredNews" >
        <div class="name" >
            <p class="desc_top_time">{{row.created_at}}</p>
                <span class="last_p"> {{row.category}}</span>
            <h3 style="margin-bottom:-4px; font-size: 16px;">
    <router-link class="btn btn-primary" v-bind:to="{name: 'Topnews', params: {id: row.id}  }">{{row.title}}</router-link></h3>
        </div></div></div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            news: [],
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        let uri = '/news';
        Axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
            this.news = response.data;
        });
    },
    computed: {
        filteredNews: function() {
            if (this.news.length) {
                return this.news;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Topnews.vue

```
<template id="topnews1">
<div class="col-sm-7">
<div class="cars">
<img :src="topnews.thumb" class="img-responsive" width=100%/>
<div class="name" ><h3>{{ topnews.title }}</h3>
<p> 
<br>{{ topnews.info }}<br/>
</p>
</div></div></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
        data:function(){
               return {topnews: {title: '', thumb: '', info: ''}}
        },
        created:function()  {
            let uri = '/news/'+this.$route.params.id;
            Axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
                this.topnews = response.data;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like GoogleMac said Vue will reuse the same component whenever possible. Since the route for both IDs use the same component Vue will not recreate it, so the `created()` method is only being called on the first page. You'll need to use the routers [beforeRouteUpdate](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) to capture the route change and update the data.

in TopNews.vue:

```
export default {
        data:function(){
               return {topnews: {title: '', thumb: '', info: ''}}
        },
        beforeRouteEnter:function(to, from, next)  {
            let uri = '/news/'+ to.params.id;

            Axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
                next(vm => {
                    vm.setData(response.data)
                })
            });
        },
        beforeRouteUpdate: function(to, from, next) {
            let uri = '/news/'+ to.params.id;
            Axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
                this.setData(response.data);
                next();
            });

        },
        methods: {
            setData(data) {
                this.topnews = data
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out! This works, but only after first switch - news1 -> news2 works;  news2 -> news1 doesn't work. Though adding ":key="$route.fullPath" in router-view in welcome.blade.php, fixes it. I don't know if it's a good practice tho, because when it updates, it moves 2 pixels from right, then gets centered at the same place, but thats bugging me out, is there any way I can use your code not only to work for the first switch, as with your code that 'moving' issue isn't happening. Thank you again!

Comment: `:key="$route.fullPath` works because it forces Vue to recreate the component for every route. That basically disables an optimization that Vue does automatically. Whether it is a problem or not depends on the size of your project. Try adding `next()` inside the promise inside the `beforeRouteUpdate`. I think the missing `next()` call may have been the problem, but I updated my answer to also replace the created method with `beforeRouteEnter()` which is more idiomatic when using vue-router.

Comment: Works perfect now, accepted your answer! Thank you so much !!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you click a link referring to the page you are on, nothing will change. Vue Router is smart enough to not make any changes.

My guess is that the IDs are messed up. If you are using Vue devtools you will be able to easily see what data is in each link. Are they as you expect.

Comment: I fetch the results from the database and router-link get 2 links currently - /news/1 and /news/2/

Comment: Thanks for responding. I already checked them, they give out the correct data. Read my answer to jfadich